# How can I install Aperture on a Mac Mini?

Tags: install, mac-mini

A friend of mine just purchased a new Mac Mini, and ordered Aperture at the same time.

It shipped on a DVD, and of course the Mini does not have a DVD drive.  She currently has a laptop running Windows, but when she inserts the DVD into the Windows laptop, the drive appears empty.

Is there any way to install the program on her Mac short of buying an external DVD player?  Will her license code allow her to download Aperture from the app store without another purchase?

Comment: If you cannot find a suitable DVD drive I would suggesting calling Apple. They can likely credit you for the app and perhaps migrate your purchase through to the App Store (where it is substantially cheaper): http://www.steves-digicams.com/news/get_aperture_on_the_cheap_at_the_mac_app_store.html#b (1-800-MY-APPLE)

Answer (score 6):

Several options:

- Remote Disk (using another drive over the network)
- MacBook Air SuperDrive
- other USB external drives
- Pay again and download over the App Store.

---

The cheapest, possibly fastest is the first option:

- [MacBook Air, Mac mini: How to use Remote Disc to share DVDs or CDs from a Mac or Windows-based computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1777)

The license code is non-transferable from physical media to the App Store, but perhaps you could sell your old version to someone that didn't like the store restrictions to subsidize or cover the cost?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Remote Disk feature to install the software.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1777

Answer (score 0):

Buy the latest version of Aperture from the App Store.  It's a vast improvement over the previous versions and a fairly cheap upgrade.